# Run a script when a process throws stderr message

Tags: process, stderr

I want to "wrap" a process around another to catch `stderr` messages when they occur.

**Use Case**

I'm using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) and I have to have a terminal open and see if there is something wrong. My plan is to use [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) tool to send myself OSX notifications so I notice an error happened. Then I don't have to keep terminal open on my screen all the time.

Imagine I have all this notification mechanism under a shell script named `compass-error.sh` which will send a notification when you call it. Now I want to run `compass watch` with my main process and watch for `stderr` to fire `compass-error.sh`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output="$(./compass 2>&1 1>/dev/null)"
if [ -n "$output" ]; then
  echo "$output" | mail ...
fi
```